# Using a loop to create multiple lists with user inputs

Tags: python, list, loops, input

I'm trying to create 13 different lists (student1 to student13), all with the same structure. Each list has to be filled with the following inputs.

```
student = []

name = input('Input the name of the student: ')

password = input('Input the 8 digit password: ')
while len(password) != 8:

    print('Password is not 8 digits long!')
    password = input('Input the 8 digit password: ')

grade1 = float(input('Input the first grade between 0 and 10: '))
while grade1 < 0 or grade1 > 10:

    print('Invalid grade!')
    grade1 = float(input('Input the first grade between 0 and 10: '))

grade2 = float(input('Input the second grade between 0 and 10: '))
while grade2 < 0 or grade2 > 10:

    print('Invalid grade!')
    grade2 = float(input('Insert the second grade between 0 and 10: '))

average = (grade1 + grade2) / 2

student.append(name)
student.append(password)
student.append(average)
```

Is there a way to create a loop to fill 13 different lists with these inputs, or do I have to manually create the inputs for each of the lists?

Comment: Yes, fortunately you can use a loop and don't have to repeat the code 13 times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972761)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you really want to use `input()` for that task, but here you go:
`students` is a list of lists with 13 elements, one for each student.

```
students = []

for i in range(13):
    student = []
    print(f"\nYou are working on student {i+1}")

    name = input('Input the name of the student: ')

    password = input('Input the 8 digit password: ')
    while len(password) != 8:

        print('Password is not 8 digits long!')
        password = input('Input the 8 digit password: ')

    grade1 = float(input('Input the first grade between 0 and 10: '))
    while grade1 < 0 or grade1 > 10:

        print('Invalid grade!')
        grade1 = float(input('Input the first grade between 0 and 10: '))

    grade2 = float(input('Input the second grade between 0 and 10: '))
    while grade2 < 0 or grade2 > 10:

        print('Invalid grade!')
        grade2 = float(input('Insert the second grade between 0 and 10: '))

    average = (grade1 + grade2) / 2

    student.append(name)
    student.append(password)
    student.append(average)
```